# StopValidation() In route without raiseing wsgi debugger flask wtf

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I need to overwrite the Validator in the form and apply my own validator this specific route.
When the image uploaded is not a jpg then it will not pass the `form.validate_on_submit()` check and the template will render the errors in the html. When I try to use

```
 raise StopValidation("image1 jpg only")
```

It raises it debugger and it prevents me from seeing the route. I just want it display as a field.error with the other errors.

```
 @app.route('/test',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def test():
        form.image1.validators=[]
            if request.method == "POST" and  str(request.files['image1'].filename) != "":
                 if request.files['image1'].filename.split('.',1)[1] != "jpg" :
                    raise StopValidation("image1 jpg only")
                    print "image 1 not jpg"


            if form.validate_on_submit():
                # do stuff

        return render_template('test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate only jpg file, then make a custom validation instead of using StopValidation and just define in your form.

```
def customvalidatorForImage(form, field):
    allowed_file = ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif']  # you can modify your valid file list here
    if form.image.data:
        if form.image.data.split('.',1)[1] not in allowed_file:
            raise ValidationError("Please enter a valid image file")     


class MyForm(Form):
    image = FileField("Image" , [customvalidatorForImage, validators.DataRequired("Image is required")])
```

Comment: how do i do this in the route without adding it in the class?